# How to create a PPA package from existing launchpad source package?

Tags: package-management, ppa, launchpad

There a source package for ruby1.9.1 versioned 1.9.3.194-1 on launchpad.net, at:
https://launchpad.net/debian/sid/+source/ruby1.9.1/1.9.3.194-1/

How do I upload this to my PPA and compiling it for Lucid?

These are the steps I did so far:

```
$ pull-lp-source ruby1.9.1 1.9.3.194-1
pull-lp-source: Downloading ruby1.9.1 version 1.9.3.194-1
pull-lp-source: Downloading ruby1.9.1_1.9.3.194.orig.tar.gz from archive.ubuntu.com (11.856 MiB)
pull-lp-source: Downloading ruby1.9.1_1.9.3.194-1.debian.tar.gz from archive.ubuntu.com (0.049 MiB)
dpkg-source: info: extracting ruby1.9.1 in ruby1.9.1-1.9.3.194     
dpkg-source: info: unpacking ruby1.9.1_1.9.3.194.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: unpacking ruby1.9.1_1.9.3.194-1.debian.tar.gz
...
```

Now I wanted to upload it into my PPA, but there is no `.changes` file, so it is impossible. I tried using `debuild -S` but it tries to sign using someone else key, so that is a dead end as well ...

How can I easily upload this (already existing) source package into my PPA for Ubuntu Lucid 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is super late, but I hope that it may help someone.

1. Go to the **code** section of this Launchpad source package, and select the intended branch
   [image]
2. Create a new packaging recipe
   [image]
3. Choose the PPA where you would like to build it (it will offer you to a new one). You **don't** need to change the default **recipe text**. Choose the versions of Ubuntu for which you want to build.
   [image]
4. Once you create the recipe, scroll down and request builds.
   [image]

And launchpad will build it in your PPA in some time (it may take a few minutes to a few hours to build, depending on the size of the package).

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the source packages and put them on your own PPA.

Comment: how? there is no source package that I know of, only the components for one with a missing `.changes` file.

Comment: What you could do is creating a Launchpad project where the source code (trunk branch) would be a cody of the Bazaar `lp:debian/ruby1.9.1` branch. After that, build the packages just like them and put these packages in your PPA.